# Different Asset Digests depending on css.sass or css

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

Using Rails 3.2.13 I get different asset paths for `asset_path` depending on whether or not i use `.css.sass` or just `.css` is this expected?

For example if I only have a `app/assets/stylesheets/foo.css.sass` in my stylesheet directory and nothing else, if I accidentally use an `asset_path` with the sass version I get a file that does not exist:

```
Loading production environment (Rails 3.2.13)
irb(main):001:0> helper.asset_path "foo.css.sass"
=> "/assets/foo-b148cf064a02aef053d2902b6a1fa5a9.css"
```

Using `asset_path` with just plain `css` produces the correct path.

```
irb(main):002:0> helper.asset_path "foo.css"
=> "/assets/foo-1b1fbb65d54bbc52b702c0f1d2efcc38.css"
```

Only `foo-1b1fbb65d54bbc52b702c0f1d2efcc38.css` is generated when i run `rake assets:precompile`. Does anyone know where the different hash value comes from?

Answer (score 0):

**Quick answer:** I think that hash value is generated from the latest mtime of the compiled files.

**Long answer:** I dug around and can't confirm it, but I believe I've read that this hash-type string is generated from the latest mtime of all the file(s) you want to compile.

So my guess is foo.css is newer than foo.css.sass and so that mtime wins when precompiling.

If you want to dig further into it, I've tracked it to a `digest_path` method from within [`digest_for`](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/Sprockets/Helpers/RailsHelper/AssetPaths/digest_for).